# How do CPU operations on registers affect memory?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, cpu-registers

I am trying to understand how register operations affect memory locations.
For example here are the registers and their contents

```
Registers  Values

rax         10       
rdx         40       
rcx         20   
rbx         0x3008
```

and some memory locations:

```
Memory    Values
0x2FF8     10
0x300     190
0x3008      3
0x3010     68
```

After the following operations

```
movq $0,    %rax
movq $100,  %rdx
addq %rcx,  %rax
imulq %rax, %rdx
```

Now what should be be the memory values for the above memory locations? Are they supposed to change as I change register values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No memory locations are accessed by these instructions, thus they do not change the memory. The only memory accesses that this excerpt does is to load these *instructions* opcodes and operands into the CPU.

The code is

```
   0:   48 c7 c0 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rax
   7:   48 c7 c2 64 00 00 00    mov    $0x64,%rdx
   e:   48 01 c8                add    %rcx,%rax
  11:   48 0f af d0             imul   %rax,%rdx
```

and what it does:

1. loads 0 into the `RAX` register
2. loads 100 into `RDX` register
3. increments the current value of `RAX` register by the value of `RCX` register
4. signed-multiplies the value of `RAX` by the value of `RDX` (i.e. the 100, if it wasn't changed in an interrupt in between) and stores the lowest 64 bits of the result result into `RDX`

Hence the result should be, given `rcx` as 20

```
rax         20      
rdx         2000       
rcx         20
```

and rbx unchanged.

The registers are "a kind of memory" but unlike DRAM that is very simple in structure, these are a much more complicated set of ports and wirings on the CPU silicon.

Comment: So, integer values stored in those memory addresses are not affected and remain the same? Am I correct?

Comment: @a_a_a sorry :D yea. The formatting in your Q was off. Yea, the memory stays the same.